# Why is_dir() function is not working for Network paths in PHP?

Tags: php, file-io, samba

I am checking in my code, if directory exists or not with `is_dir()`.

It works for local drives, but not for network paths.

Can anyone help me out?

Here Is My Sample Code:

```
public function setXMLFilePath($filePath) {
    if(is_dir($filePath)) {
        $this->XMLFilePath = $filePath;
        $retVal = true;
    } else {
        $ratVal = false;
    }

    return $retVal;
}//setXMLFilePath
```

And My Network Path is Like this:

```
$filePath = '\\Nas-heidi\heidi\FAS\Polish GameRobot\Export_Raffle\';
```

Comment: What syntax to you use for the LAN path? Can you post an example of line that doesn't work ?

Comment: @Hardik Kothari: Were you able to solve this problem? If yes, how? If not, what did you try, anything form the answers below? Please share.

Answer (score 0):

The file-related functions wrap over [a few protocols](http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php), the Windows networking schema is not one of them.

Also notable is the fact that when you are accessing one of these (external) protocols you should not be using shorthands such as `\\\network_computer\network_folder\` you should be using full protocol specifications such as `ftp://`/`http://`/`ssh://` and if the protocol for Windows networking existed it would probably have such an identifier.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably because the account that run PHP script (maybe the count that start the Apache service) has no permissions for such directories.